# Stretched Image within Circular Container Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create circular borders around my image. But whenever I try to fit the image into the border container, I either get the top of the image cut off or the image skewed into an ugly stretch.

Here's the code below for how I create the bordered circular image:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 3,)
      ),
      child: Container(
        width: width,
        height: height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2,),
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: image,
              fit: BoxFit.fill
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

But here's how the images turn out:
[image: Sample Image]

I really just want the full image size, but scaled down to whatever container surrounds it. I don't want it stretched and I don't want too much of the image cropped out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use [BoxFit.cover](https://docs-flutter-io.firebaseapp.com/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html) instead of fill.

Answer (score 0):

Use CircleAvatar as a child to the container to display the image.

- Container with border and padding

  - CircleAvatar

    - background image url with radius

Comment: This works fine for the bad stretch, but it does not solve the problem of the unwanted crop (especially the top of the image). The radius seems to have no effect on the image